# Tell if string is pixels or percent then divide by two

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function that well allow the user to define a custom width either as pixels or percents.

The problem is I need to get half of the number they provide. Here is a example of what I am trying to do:

User Enters----------Expected Result

```
50%            25%
300px          150px
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A simpler web form would let the user select % or px separately (say, with a pair of radio buttons), not enter it into the same textfield as the number. Otherwise, this sounds like a job for [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: This is for a plugin, one of the parameters the user can fill in is the width. Sorry should have included this.

Comment: `if ( str.indexOf('%') != -1 ) var halfPct = (parseInt(str,10)/2) + '%';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, although you should probably validate their input first.

```
parseInt(str) / 2 + str.match(/(%|px)$/)[0]
```

Without validation, this throws an error if the input doesn't end in `%` or `px` (can't do `null[0]`).  If instead you want to have missing or unrecognized units treated as `%` by default, you could do this:

```
parseInt(str) / 2 + (str.match(/(%|px)$/)||["%"])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex based `String.replace` in combination with a callback:

```
"50px".replace(/(\d+)(%|px)/, function (_, value, unit) { 
    return String(value / 2) + unit; 
});
// returns 25px
```